# React-Native: Unable to run application on API 16 device. Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: android, react-native

I am attempting to run a `react-native` application on my Samsung Galaxy S3 running `4.1.2`. According to the [docs](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/e2841c05b4bc67aad90854c7013b278ca4abe03a) this version is supported.

I use `create-react-native-app` and have created a simple unmodified application. I attempt to run it on the device using `yarn run android` but I get the following error:

```
Error running adb: Error running app. Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=exp://192.168.0.10:19000 flg=0x10000000 }
(node:58131) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at /xdl/src/Android.js:88:18
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/spongebob/Projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/xdl/build/Android.js:473:191)
    at /Users/spongebob/Projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/xdl/build/Android.js:473:361
    at <anonymous>
(node:58131) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

My phone is connected:

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
4790207223d13060    device
```

I had this problem when attempting to run with Genymotion, but I solved it by creating an emulator using `API 19`. My phone is `API 16`.

Any idea why I'm getting this error? I don't want to update this Samsung as I specifically want to test applications on API 16. I just can't understand why it's not running if API 16 is supported.

Here's some additional info:

```
Environment:
  OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.6
  Node: 9.5.0
  Yarn: 1.3.2
  npm: 5.6.0
  Watchman: Not Found
  Xcode: Not Found
  Android Studio: 3.0 AI-171.4443003

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.2.0 => 16.2.0
  react-native: 0.54.0 => 0.54.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after changed os from ubuntu to windows 10.

I solved by following:

1.set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME='my-custom-ip-address-or-hostname'

2. Check do you added JAVA_HOME and Path variables in System Advanced Settings.
3. Install Expo latest version apk into your emulator manually(because npm run android doesnt automatically install expo to emulator).
4. Then give npm run android.

Its worked for me.